# Build problem with inline definitions in MPLAB (c compiler, MCC foundation function)

Tags: c, build, inline, mcc

Using MPLAB with MCC to build basic c application (xc16 compiler), I'm getting messages like:

> build/default/debug/mcc_generated_files/drivers/timeout.o(.text+0x4e):
> In function `_timeout_getTimeRemaining': : undefined reference to` _makeAbsolute'

However, the function `_makeAbsolute` *is* defined in the same code module as the calling function - in fact a few lines above it.

Any idea what I am missing please?

I was expecting MCC foundation service to just work but there must be something missing - it may be more generic build issue with 'inline' function.

Comment: I know how to fix it - simply remove the 'inline' prefix to each function. Can anyone help explain why 'inline' doesn't work - is a feature of the xc16 compiler or how should the code be written to get the benefit of inline which is presumably speed of execution.

Comment: I had the same error after using MCC.  Your solution got me thinking.  Inline must have worked at some point...  So, I tried out all 3 compilers.  It appears that the only compiler which works is XC16 v1.41 (the older version).  Actually, a TON of issues I was having went away when I switched to the older version of XC16.